# networking help on Solaris

Tags: networking, tcp, routes, solaris

I have two network interfaces on my Solaris machine and the output of ifconfig -a looks like below:

```
lo0: flags=1000849<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 8232 index 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask ff000000
bge0: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 2
        inet 10.17.56.150 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.17.56.255
        ether 0:14:4f:7e:4a:68
bge1: flags=1000843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST,IPv4> mtu 1500 index 3
    inet 10.0.226.166 netmask ffffff00 broadcast 10.255.255.255
    ether 0:14:4f:7e:4a:69
```

My routing table looks like below:

```
# netstat -nr

Routing Table: IPv4
Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref   Use   Interface
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ------ ---------
10.17.56.0           10.17.56.150         U         1   5670  bge0
10.0.226.0           10.0.226.166         U         1   1107  bge1
224.0.0.0            10.17.56.150         U         1      0  bge0
default              10.0.226.1           UG        1      0
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        8 162738  lo0
```

I have an application running which is listening on port 7710 on interface bge0.

The problem is that from an external machine when I try to telnet to 10.17.56.150 on port 7710, it works. But on the other interface it does not work i.e. telnet to 10.0.226.166 on port 7710 does not work. There is no firewall in between.

Can anybody help what is wrong and how can this be achieved. I want to be able to telnet to 10.0.226.166 on port 7710.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you ping 10.0.226.166?  Are you sure your service is bound to bge1 on tcp/7710

Comment: yes I can ping to both IP addresses on both interfaces. I can telnet to 10.17.56.150:7710 but cannot telnet to 10.0.226.166:7710.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can ping bge1, but cannot connect to tcp/7710 on bge1, then the most likely causes are:

- You have not bound your service to bge1 on tcp/7710.  Check this by looking at `netstat -an | grep 10.0.226.166`.
- There is a firewall or router ACL in the path blocking your traffic